# Why SFINAE results in compiler error where it should have worked?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, sfinae

I was trying to implement a meta-program which finds if given pointer type is `const` or not. i.e.

- `is_const<TYPE*>::value` should be `false`
- `is_const<const TYPE*>::value` should be `true`

Following is the code:

```
template<class TYPE>
struct is_const
{
  typedef char yes[3];
  template<typename T>
  struct Perform
  {
    static yes& check (const T*&);
    static char check (T*&);
  };  

  TYPE it; 
  enum { value = (sizeof(Perform<TYPE>::check(it)) == sizeof(yes)) };  
};
```

And the compiler error messages are:

```
In instantiation of ‘is_const<int*>’:
instantiated from here
error: no matching function for call to ‘is_const<int*>::Perform<int*>::check(int*&)’
note: candidates are: static char (& is_const<TYPE>::Perform<T>::check(const T*&))[3] [with T = int*, TYPE = int*]
note: static char is_const<TYPE>::Perform<T>::check(T*&) [with T = int*, TYPE = int*]
```

My focus has shifted to the error message. If you see the last line:

```
note: static char is_const<TYPE>::Perform<T>::check(T*&) [with T = int*, TYPE = int*]
```

If we really replace `T = int*` and `TYPE = int*` then it really should match the appropriate function (`char check()`). I am anxious to know that what is going wrong here.

Comment: If `T` is `int *`, then `T *&` is `int **&`.  So I do not think the signatures match...

Comment: @iammilind: No, it should not match, you have `void foo( int **& )` and `int *p; foo( p );`, `p` is a pointer to int, not a pointer to a pointer to int.

Answer (score 9):

Why so roundabout? How about a straight-forward trait class:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T> struct is_const_ptr : std::false_type { };
template <typename T> struct is_const_ptr<const T *> : std::true_type { };

struct Foo {};

int main()
{
  std::cout << is_const_ptr<Foo*>::value << is_const_ptr<const Foo*>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: +1, even if it is unclear in the question what is it that he wants to check, whether the outer type or the pointed to type in the case of a pointer are const... and I would remove the `*` from the specialization...

Comment: @Dribeas: Just `is_const`? But we're testing for "pointer-to-const-T", not for "const pointer-to-T"...

Comment: That is why I upvoted, as this answer is clear: `is_const_ptr` is quite explicit.

Comment: @Dribeas: Yeah, but how could you remove the `*` from the specialization and retain the check for "pointer-to-const"?

Comment: Sometimes people have to agree in disagreeing. In our case we are disagreeing in the agreement. I should have been clearer before, so I am going to try harder now, my problem is not with your answer, but with the question where he calls the template `is_const` but actually tests for `is_const_ptr`. What I intended to say before is that I would have gone for the *name is right, implementation is wrong* approach (i.e. implement `is_const`)

Comment: @dribeas: Ahh - now we can agree to agree!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
static yes& check (const T*&);
static char check (T*&);
```

When you instantiate `is_const<int*>`, your function definitions are expanded to:

```
static yes& check (const int**&);
static char check (int**&);
```

However, your temporary item (`TYPE it`) is of type `int*`, like you specified. You need to change your `check` function signatures to remove the pointer specifier, like so:

```
static yes& check (const T&);
static char check (T&);
```

Comment: Kind of right... in the case of the `const` check, the signature would probably be `static yes& check( int * const * & )` rather than `static yes& check( int const ** & )` as you have stated.

Comment: I have tried this modification, but still it doesn't seem to work. See output at http://www.ideone.com/fMlxb

Answer (score 1):

THere are two things wrong in your code.

First, the following

```
static yes& check (const T*&);
static char check (T*&);
```

must be changed to

```
static yes& check (const T&);
static char check (T&);
```

Ans second, the `it` member must be `static`

```
static TYPE it;
```

or, just pass `((TYPE)0)` to your check function. No need of the member.

Comment: +1  `(sizeof(Perform<TYPE>::check((TYPE)0))` will be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: It would be evaluated at compile time if it were `check(it)`, too, @VJo.

Comment: I have tried this modification, but still it doesn't seem to work. See output at http://www.ideone.com/fMlxb